# Why is my Ajax posted data not in the right format?

Tags: ajax, axios

I'm writing a plugin for Wordpress that uses VueJS. Everything works fine until I come to send the data via a Ajax POST request.
Here is an extract of what I have:

```
data () { 
  return {
    form: {
      items: []
    }
  }
}

methods: {
  processOrder () {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/ajax.php',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        action: "process_order"
      })
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

and when I examine the request in Chrome I get:

```
"body":"{\"action\":\"process_order\"}"
```

which means the action key is never found on the server. If I take out the Stringify then the server sees nothing. Any ideas on how to remove the escaping?

Comment: Oh, ignore the data() reference, I took it out while testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can try this

```
npm install qs --save-dev
```

and use:

```
import Qs from qs
data:Qs.stringify({action: "process_order"})
```